# Clearfix group not working in UL

Tags: html, css, css-float, clearfix

I am trying to align horizontally my UL item but it is not working. I have already used "group" clear-fix code in another div, there it is working perfectly.
kindly help me.

html code.

```
<div class="contain">

<header>
    <h1>Hello !</h1>
    <p>Zeeshan here</p>

    <nav class="site-nav">
      <ul class="group">
          <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Category</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Media</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>  
</header>
```

.
Css code

```
.group:before,
.group:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
} 
.group:after {
   content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
.group {
    zoom: 1; /* For IE 6/7 (trigger hasLayout) */
}
```

.contain

```
.contain
{

    width: 800px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;

}
```

.site-nav

```
.site-nav li
{
    list-style: none;
    float: lef;
}
```

Comment: Can you post the CSS code for `.contain` and `.site-nav`? As it stands we *cannot* find out what the bug actually is that you're experiencing even tho a quick guess of mine would be that you have `float: left;` elements but that doesn't help us reproduce the issue.

Comment: typo error change `float: lef;` to `float: left;`

Comment: already fixed that issue. still facing problem !

Comment: i reopen my browser and issue resolved . lol

Comment: thanx for your trime

Answer (score 1):

All you want is your floated elements to be on one line e.g. inline to each other.

As a matter of fact there are multiple approaches. Yours works but you had a typo causing your `float` not to work.

All you have to do to see how this float is affecting your menu *visually* is by adding a `background` property to your element.

e.g.

```
.site-nav ul {
    background: #09c;
}

.site-nav ul li {
    float: left;
}
```

Your class `group` is working as intended, it clears the float correctly.
However you don't even need the `group` class if you don't use `float` but instead use `display: inline-block` - it has other issues like causing whitespace between your elements but that can be fixed in multiple *other* ways than floats.

One of these is setting the `font-size` property of the `ul` to `0px` and resetting it on the nested `li` to be `[your-size]px`.

Your HTML would be simpler as you wouldn't need the `group` class on your `ul` and since `inline-block` elements are basically `inline` elements with `block` properties (like `width`, `height`) you can also use `text-*` properties to align items, they effectively become text so you can manipulate them like text.

An example using `inline-block`

```
.site-nav ul {
    background: #09c;
    font-size: 0;
    /*text-align: center;*/ /*uncomment if you want to see alignment of items*/
}

.site-nav ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 16px; /*example value*/
}
```

May I also point out that using the word `group` as name for the `clearfix` is unclear? It's better to just name it `clearfix` since that's *exactly* what it does and another programmer will understand this, if not (s)he will google `clearfix` and find the direct answer instantly anyways.

`group` is a very global uncategorized name so you want to be careful with what you use it for if maintainability is required.

Answer (score 0):

https://jsfiddle.net/wr5uhxne/1/

I copied your html and css and aligned the list items to the center, hope it is helpful.

The change I made was in the group style:

```
.group {
    zoom: 1; /* For IE 6/7 (trigger hasLayout) */
    text-align:center;
}
```

Comment: look at the jsfiddle, is that what you meant?

Comment: no dear, i want to horizontally align Home category etc list items.

Comment: i reopen my beowser and issue resolved . lol
thanx for your time

Comment: in that case it was probably the browser cache, try refreshing using ctrl+f5 to delete cache or run in incognito